# How to get rid of material distortion?

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, texture-coordinates

Help me figure out what am I doing wrong here, Tried modeling it again but, this issue still persists. What is the reason for this distortion and how do I correct it?.
Ps. I tried UV unwrapping and added texture coordinates, nothing seems to work.[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: since we don't see your geometry and it looks like you are not that experienced you should provide your blend file

Comment: Hi! Yes I am still on the learning curve  I have added the blend file @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieved the brushed metal look by stretching the Noise Texture on the X-axis, but you need to do so for the Z-axis as well, so it also works "up and down":

[image: Stretch]

2 things to note here, however - 1. because you are using *Object* texture coordinates, changes you make to one axis (such as stretching with a *Mapping Node*), often affect the others. Increasing the Z-axis stretch will also affect the X-axis - because of this you may want to back off on the X as you increase the Z.

[image: Stretch2]

2. doing this will cause the "front and back" of the object to stretch accordingly (because you are using object texture coordinates - see image above), if you want the best chance of having a proper "brushed look" all over the metal, you are probably best to use UV texture coordinates:

[image: UV]

Doing this, however will require a proper UV map (which you already seem to have) - yours seems to be in pretty good order, save for the strange (unnatural) direction of some of the brush marks (to fix this, just select the necessary UV island(s) with L and move/rotate them as necessary). There is also a visible seam on one side which unfortunately cannot be avoided, however you can place it somewhere less visible.

[image: UV2]

Comment: Thank you very much, for the thoroughly explained solution! @Christopher Bennett